# Extract URL from below code with beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, extract

```html
<li class="option image" data-originalv="https://yellow_28_38_0_z_2.jpg" data-id="16693" data-pname="Yellow Classic Fit Casual Shirt"
data-purl="https://www.my-required-link-classic-fit-yellow-shirt.html">
<img loading="lazy" src="https://www.myimage-yellow_28_38_0_z_2.jpg" alt="" title="" width="40" height="40"></li>
```

I wanted to extract the **data-purl** link. How can i do that with beautiful soup

Answer (score 0):

To access the attribute of a tag simply call `get('attribute')` or treat it like a dict `['attribute']`:

```
soup.find('li').get('data-purl')
```

or

```
soup.find('li')['data-purl']
```

#### Example

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
html='''
<li class="option image" data-originalv="https://yellow_28_38_0_z_2.jpg" data-id="16693" data-pname="Yellow Classic Fit Casual Shirt"
data-purl="https://www.my-required-link-classic-fit-yellow-shirt.html">
<img loading="lazy" src="https://www.myimage-yellow_28_38_0_z_2.jpg" alt="" title="" width="40" height="40"></li>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.find('li').get('data-purl')
```

#### Output

```
https://www.my-required-link-classic-fit-yellow-shirt.html
```